# Filtering Middleware Frames from Stack Trace Logs in JBoss 7 with Filter-spec

Tags: logging, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I want to reduce the length of my exception logging on JBoss 7 while losing as little valuable information as possible. What I am trying to do is to filter out any JBoss middleware stack frames which usual provide litle insight into actual issues in application code.
Example of frames I am trying to filter: "at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)" or " at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)".

I have been able filter out regular log entries completely using a ***filter-spec*** in the logging configuration in the JBoss configuration file:

```
<console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <level name="TRACE" />
    <formatter>
    <pattern-formatter
            pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n" />
</formatter>
    <filter-spec value="not(match(&quot;Validation&quot;))" />
</console-handler>
```

I have also been able to replace log entries that match a particular filter expression:

```
<console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <level name="TRACE" />
    <formatter>
    <pattern-formatter
            pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n" />
</formatter>
    <filter-spec value="substituteAll(&quot;Validation&quot;, &quot;Im here!!!!&quot;)" />
    <filter-spec value="not(match(&quot;Validation&quot;))" />
</console-handler>
```

But when I try to substitute an exception stacktrace frame instead of a regular log entry it does not work. the filter-spec I am trying to use is:

```
<filter-spec value="substituteAll(&quot;sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl&quot;, &quot;&quot;)" />
```

But this filter seems to ignore stack traces.

Can anyone suggest a way to filter these stack traces in a JBoss environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately filters don't work on exceptions. Also currently there's no ability to use custom filters either. You can however either use a `custom-formatter` or `custom-handler` which could do that for your.

An example custom handler could look something like:

```java
public class TrimCauseHandler extends Handler {

    private Handler delegate;

    @Override
    public synchronized void publish(final LogRecord record) {
        if (delegate != null) {
            final Throwable cause = record.getThrown();
            if (cause != null) {
                final Collection<StackTraceElement> st = new ArrayList<>();
                for (StackTraceElement e : cause.getStackTrace()) {
                    final String className = e.getClassName();
                    if (className.startsWith("org.jboss.as") || className.startsWith("org.wildfly")) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    st.add(e);
                }
                cause.setStackTrace(st.toArray(new StackTraceElement[0]));
            }
            record.setThrown(cause);
            delegate.publish(record);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void flush() {
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.flush();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() throws SecurityException {
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.close();
        }
    }

    public synchronized Handler getDelegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

    public synchronized void setDelegate(final Handler delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
}
```

Then a CLI command to use it for the console handler would be something like:

```
/subsystem=logging/custom-handler=test:add(module=your.module, class=org.jboss.example.handlers.TrimCauseHandler, properties={delegate="CONSOLE"})
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:remove-handler(name=CONSOLE)
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:add-handler(name=test)
```

It doesn't look like arrays are supported property types so you'd have to wrap each handler in a `TrimCauseHandler` or do something odd like make `setDelegate()` add the handler to a collection of some sort.

### Update

I just want to point out there is now an open [JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-4336) to allow for custom filters.